# Unclear regex Pattern

Tags: r, grepl

Can anyone explain how pattern is being found out here?grepl and gsub is fine out here.But the patterns are not easily understood

```
 if (grepl("\\(.*?\\)", name)){     
     gsub("^.*?\\((.*?)\\)$", "\\1", name)
 }
```

Comment: they uses [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), unless you set parameter fixed=TRUE, in that case they just search the pattern string (as it is) inside the character vectors.

Answer (score 0):

**\\(.*?\\):**

```
\\ -> \
  ( -> (
   . -> .
    * -> zero ore more times the last character
      ? -> last item is optional (not needed here)
       \\ -> \
         ) -> )
```

So this gets all strings like `\(\)`, `\(.\)`, `\(....\)`

**^.*?\\((.*?)\\)$:**

```
^.*?\\((.*?)\\)$
^ -> Beginning of line
 . -> .
  * -> zero or more times last item
   ? -> optional last item (not needed here)
     \\ -> \
       ((. -> ((.
          * -> zero or more times
           ? -> optional last item
            )\\ -> )\
              $ -> End of line
```

Please see the [R documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) about regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [regex101](https://regex101.com/) for a detail explanation of your pattern.

`"` matches the character `"` literally (case sensitive)
`\\` matches the character `\` literally (case sensitive)
1st Capturing Group `(.*?\\)`
`.*?` matches any character (except for line terminators)
`*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
`\\` matches the character `\` literally (case sensitive)